# Excel Conditional Formatting for positive and negative percentages not working

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a silly problem - I have a calculated cell which will result in a percentage that can be positive or negative and I have 3 conditional rules set up to colour the cell Red, Amber or Green based on a set of criteria other cells.

While the CF is working when the result is positive (e.g. <30% is Red, 30% to 50% is Amber and >50% is Green) as soon as the result is a negative figure the cell stays white. Surely a result of -60% is <30% so *should* trigger the Red CF??

EDIT: here is the CF formula for red:
[[Cell Value]-[less than]-[=LOOKUPS!$G$33]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTTZL.png) and [LOOKUPS!$G$33 is 30%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxGBC.png)

[image: Screenshot of Conditional Formatting: Cell Value is Less Than Lookups cell G33]

[image: Screenshot of Lookup table - cell G33 is 30%]

I don't know if this matters but both the result and the CF criteria are both formatted as percentages.

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Pictures of the settings for each rule? Could be something you missed

Comment: What colour is -10%?

Comment: @Jerry I have added pictures

Comment: @Chronocidal The result is a performance score so ANYTHING less than 30% should be red

Comment: That's strange. I get the desired behaviour [when I do it on my local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjwGk.png).

Comment: @Jerry Could it be due to formatting? e.g. the calculation formula is =IF(F32=0,"-",F32/G32*100%) and the lookup for the CF is simply types as 30% - could that be a problem? Should I boil everything down to decimal places and just format them as percentages?

Comment: @Jerry Having said that - even if the result is -0.2 then it should still be 'less than 30%'??

Comment: @AlanEnglefield My reasoning was that if -10% was red, but -60% was not, then it might be reading the *absolute* value (i.e. treating -60% and 60% the same)

Comment: Yes, even -1 should become red with that CF. If you do get F32 as 0 however, you will get the text `-` which will become white (just a side mention). The formatting should be fine IMO. 0.6 = 60%. I'm stumped. Any chance for you to put a small dummy excel with the issue on a file hosting site and link it here?

Comment: @Chronocidal Ahh I see the confusion now :o)

Comment: @AlanEnglefield Can you add a screenshot showing the cells that the conditional formatting should be applying to, with various values (e.g. 40%, 20%, 0%, -60%) - and, are there any *other* Format Conditions that might be interfering?

Comment: @Jerry here is a stripped down sample of the file https://filebin.net/3z41pjlhbxdtx8ca/2020_Scorecard_SAMPLE.xlsx?t=fkwalgvy

Comment: @Chronocidal I have added a link to the file in my previous comment which includes 2 entries with different values - thanks

Comment: It was as @Chronocidal said. There is another CF interfering, the one checking for the presence of `-`. Move this down (select the rule, [click on the arrow down button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e42wf.png)) and that click on OK/Apply and that should do it.

Comment: Arrrrrgh!! I knew it was something silly. Thanks guys; I've changed the 'contains' to 'ends with' and it's all good. That CF was supposed to be "if the cell shows - then don't colour it" but of course the 'contains' skewed it up haha

Comment: @Chronocidal & Jerry - how do I give you both props?

Comment: Wait for Chronological to put an answer so you can mark it as accepted. I didn't consider that possibility before he mentioned it :)